# Proof Check: Expectation of geometric random variable using linearity of expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

**Question**:
Find the expected hitting time of the first 6 on throw of a dice.

**Answer 1**:
Proceed to find the expectation of geometric RV through regular summation of infinite series.

**Alternative Answer**:
Can we get expected hitting time of the first six using linearity of expectation?

---

Let a coin be thrown $N$ times.
Let $X_i$ be an indicator of the i'th throw being a 6.
Let $X = \sum_{i\in[N]} X_i$

$\mathbb{E}  [X] = \mathbb{E}  [\sum_{i\in[N]} X_i] = N\mathbb{E}  [X_i] =  \frac{N}{6} -(A)$

Therefore the number of times we expect to see a '6' in N draws is $\frac{N}{6}$. Next I wish to show that the expcted hitting time for the first six is the least $N$ such that $\frac{N}{6}\geq 1$, or in other words the expected hitting time is $6$.

---

Let the Hitting time for first '6' be $H$ and let $[j] = \{1,2,\dots,j\}$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[H] &= \mathbb{E} \left[\min_{i} X_i = 1\right]
= \mathbb{E} \left[\min_{j} \sum_{i\in [j]} X_i = 1\right]
= \mathbb{E} \left[\min_{j} \sum_{i\in [j]} X_i \geq 1\right]
\end{align*}

Consider all $j$ such that $\sum_{i\in [j]} X_i \geq 1$ as a vector. We take expectation of such a vector. Then $\mathbb{E}[H]$ is the first element (least value) of such a vector.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[H]   = \mathbb{E} \left[j \ \bigg |\  \sum_{i\in [j]} X_i \geq 1\right]_1
\end{align*}

here $[\cdot]_1$ indicates the first element or coordinate of the vector and $[ j \mid \dots]$ indicates "j such that...".

Since the expectation goes through elementwise:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[H]   &= \left[\mathbb{E} \left [j \ \bigg |\   \sum_{i\in [j]} X_i \geq 1\right]\right]_1
= \left[j \ \bigg |\   \mathbb{E} \left [\sum_{i\in [j]} X_i\right] \geq 1\right]_1
\end{align*}

But from $(A)$, $\mathbb{E} \left [\sum_{i\in [j]} X_i\right] = \frac{j}{6}$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[H]   &= \left[j \ \bigg |\   \frac{j}{6} \geq 1\right]_1
= \left[j \ \big |\   j \geq 6\right]_1
= 6
\end{align*}

I am told the above is incorrect. Specifically in the penultimate step where I move the expectation over the indices $j$ to the summation.

**Question**:
Is it really wrong? Is there a way to make it work?